# Web app to take screen shot of website and annotate?

Tags: web-development, looking-for-a-script

Does anyone know of a website that will take a full screen shot of another website and let users write notes over it then send that annotated photo by email or private link? Basically looking for quicker way to write notes on a site other than taking a screen shot my self and putting it into photoshop.

Just an update, I don't need any browser extensions which I already have and do the same. I'm looking for a website app which does this to give to a client.

Comment: If you're using Google Chrome and just want to take a screenshot and annotate and only after you're done, send it to other people, I can recommend the "Awesome Screenshot: Capture & Annotate" extension for Chrome. But I don't know of any web app or service which would do it.

Comment: Already have that installed for myself. I need to find a website that does the same to give to a client so they can easily add some notes to a site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Notable](http://www.notableapp.com/) provides a shared interface for making notes on pages, as well as a few other document formats, if it ever comes up.